# Python for-loops of 3D cupy arrays on GPU, when array broadcast is not possible

Tags: python, gpu, numba, cupy

I'm trying to use cupy with GPU (NVIDIA K6000 with 2880 cores) to accelerate some for-loops over several 3-dimensional arrays in Python; as shown by the example code below. I define a function that takes the 3D arrays as input argument, performs the for-loops, and outputs an array. I run two cases and compare the execution times: (1) jit-compiled function containing for-loop processing two numpy arrays (A_cpu, B_cpu), in parallel on 4 CPU cores, and (2) the for-loop is called on two cupy arrays (A_gpu, B_gpu), on the 2880 GPU cores. I get the same values from each case; however, the cupy GPU execution is significantly slower than the numpy CPU execution; as shown in the results below. I am not able to use array broadcasting (A[i, :, :]) to eliminate any of the {i, j, k} for-loops, because array indexing is not uniform across operations.

I should add that the math operations in the actual code are much more complex and involve around 12 different 3D arrays; however, for the sake of brevity here I just showed the array-indexing interdependence. Also, running the actual code with @jit(parallel=True) significantly accelerates the code on 4-cores CPU compared to non-parallel jit, which is why I suspect it should be amenable to even more massive parallelization on 2880-cores GPU.

The example Python code is below:

```
import numpy as np
import cupy as cp
from time import time
from numba import cuda, jit, prange

M = 100
N = 100
P = 10
A_cpu = np.random.rand(M, N, P)
B_cpu = np.random.rand(M, N, P)
A_gpu = cp.asarray(A_cpu) 
B_gpu = cp.asarray(B_cpu) 

print('Being CPU test:')
@jit(parallel=True)
def cpu_loop(A_cpu, B_cpu):
    for i in prange(1, M-1):
        for j in prange(1, N-1):
            for k in prange(1, P-1):
                A_cpu[i, j, k] = (A_cpu[i-1, j-1, k+1]*2 - A_cpu[i, j+1, k-1]/2) / (B_cpu[i+1, j+1, k-1]*2 - B_cpu[i, j-1, k+1]/2)
    return(A_cpu)
start = time()
cpu_res = cpu_loop(A_cpu, B_cpu)
end = time()

cpu_total_time = end - start
print('CPU result = ', cpu_res[M//2, N//2, P//2])
print('CPU total_time = {:2.3f} seconds'.format(cpu_total_time))

print('Begin GPU test:')
def gpu_loop(A_gpu, B_gpu):
    for i in prange(1, M-1):
        for j in prange(1, N-1):
            for k in prange(1, P-1):
                A_gpu[i, j, k] = (A_gpu[i-1, j-1, k+1]*2 - A_gpu[i, j+1, k-1]/2) / (B_gpu[i+1, j+1, k-1]*2 - B_gpu[i, j-1, k+1]/2)
    return(A_gpu)
start = time()
gpu_res = gpu_loop(A_gpu, B_gpu)
end = time()

gpu_total_time = end - start
print('GPU result = ', gpu_res[M//2, N//2, P//2])
print('GPU total_time = {:2.3f} seconds'.format(gpu_total_time))
```

The output of above code is below:

```
Being CPU test:
CPU result =  208.3083524104198
CPU total_time = 2.117 seconds
Begin GPU test:
GPU result =  208.3083524104198
GPU total_time = 33.462 seconds
```

Any insights or advice is greatly appreciated in advance!

Comment: cupy doesn't accelerate CPU for-loops.  And the actual operation you are doing nested way down inside the for-loop is trivial, arithmetically, but must be launched individually per loop iteration, on the GPU.  This is not how you speed anything up with cupy. I would say try a cupy kernel (or numba) but you have a loop-carried dependency in `A` which would generally prevent parallelization.  For that reason, I don't think your use of `prange` makes any sense.

Comment: Thanks Robert, for the quick reply. The actual math operations are much more complex and involve around 12 different 3D arrays; however, for the sake of brevity here I just showed the array-indexing interdependence. I should add that, running the actual code with @jit(parallel=True) significantly accelerates the code on 4-cores CPU compared to non-parallel jit, which is why I suspect it should be amenable to even more massive parallelization on 2880-cores GPU. Thoughts?